# Convert lasd to multipoint?

Tags: arcgis-pro, lidar, las, multipoint, lasd

Is there a way to convert an .lasd to multipoint? I created this .lasd from .laz files using the 'Convert LAS tool' in ArcGIS Pro (.las were unavailable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike LAS (.las) files, LAZ (.laz) files cannot be opened or added directly to ArcGIS Pro to display point cloud data on a map.

However, it is possible to convert the LAZ files to LAS datasets to display on the map. Use the Convert LAS tool to convert the LAZ file to a LAS dataset, and fill in the tool parameters as required. Refer to Convert LAS for more information on the tool.

[Convert LAS](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/convert-las.htm)

Finally, we can use LAS to Multipoint(3D Analyst) tool to Create multipoint features.

[LAS To Multipoint (3D Analyst)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/las-to-multipoint.htm)